# Android Instant apps, why these limitations on who can open them

Tags: android, google-play, google-people-api

Android instant apps, They sure are nice, or atleast supposed to be. We created a instant app which should be opening when scanning a QR code. THis works fine for some users for other we are experiencing some difficulties.

**The main problems are:**

**1:** *The instant app is able to load, but the users presses "open in browser" instead of "open instant app" when he is prompted to make a choice.*

This choice seems to be permanent and we haven't found a to reset this yet. If anyone knows how to reset this, or event better, circumvent the choice entirely. please enlighten me.

**2:** *Opening instant apps is turned off in the device's Google play settings.*

It's a hassle to have to explain this to users. For some reason it also seems to be turned off more often than not. Why would google promote instant apps to developers when users cant use it without flipping some obscure switch. The switch hints that there should a way to circumvent this with google play branded links. However this doesn't seem to be the case in my experience.
is there anyone out there that actually managed to generate a google play branded link that opens their instant app while the switch is turned off?

I hope that some google dev can explain some of their choices here. It seems odd that instant apps are locked behind this switch to me as opposed to iOS where other restrictions are in place but at least it functions equally for all users.

Kind regards

Wien